# Override Material Design xaml style

Tags: wpf

I would like to change the default color of material design xaml when a treeview item is selected. Here the code that I used in resource dictionary.

```
       <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:materialDesign="clr-namespace:MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;assembly=MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf"
                   >
    <Style x:Key="MaterialDesignTreeView" TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTreeView}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="MaterialDesignTreeViewItem" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I was able to override the padding but not the color of the selected treeview item. Any ideas?

Comment: If you right-click on a TreeViewItem in the XAML designer (if that's even possible...) you can to go Edit Template and find out what the style and template really look like. That will tell you how where the highlight brush is coming from.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks for the tip. I was able to get the control template of the treeviewitem and added that in the resource dictionary. changed the color of the selected item.